# 2004 Kia Spectra 1.8 Automatic - No Reverse

Tags: automatic-transmission, kia, spectra

A 2004 Kia Spectra 4cyl 1.8ltr automatic

Reverse was working fine one day then the next it no longer worked. All the other gears work fine and the transmission fluid level is where it should be. I have an automatic transmission. Any ideas on what could be the cause?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!